# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ListsController#show

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am getting the following error when trying to view the items that are contained in a list.

```
  Started GET "/lists/item" for ::1 at 2015-06-29 21:17:55 -0600
  Processing by ListsController#show as HTML
    Parameters: {"id"=>"item"}
    User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ?  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 3]]
      List Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "lists".* FROM "lists" WHERE "lists"."user_id" = ? AND "lists"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 3], ["id", 0]]
    Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find List with 'id'=item [WHERE "lists"."user_id" = ?]):
  app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:44:in `set_list'
```

Here is my Controller:

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_list


  def new
    @list = current_user.lists.new
  end

  def create
    @list = current_user.lists.build(list_params)
    if @list.save
      flash[:notice] = "Your list was created successfully"
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving your new list, please try again."
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:id])
    @items = @list.items
  end

  def edit
  end

  def update
    if @list.update_attributes(list_params)
      redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error saving your list, please try again."
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @list.destroy
  end

  private

  def set_list
    @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:id])
  end

  def list_params
    params.require(:list).permit(:name, :description)
  end

end
```

show.html.erb is

```
<div class="container">
<h1><%= @list.name %></h1>
<div class="row">
  <h2>Items</h2>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="js-items">
    <%= render :partial => 'items/item' %>
  </div>
  <div class="new-item">
    <%= render :partial => 'items/form' %>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-8">

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

The partials:

Form

```
<% if current_user %>
  <h4>Add an item:</h4>
  <%= form_for [@list, @list.items.build], remote: true do |f| %>
    <div class="form-group">
      <%= f.label :name %>
      <%= f.text_area :name, class: 'form-control', placeholder: "Enter item details" %>
      <br>
      <%= f.submit "Add Item", class: 'btn btn-primary' %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Item

```
<div class="media-body">
    <% @list.items.each do |item| %>
      <div id="<%= item.id %>">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
        <%= item.name %>
      </div>
      <div class ="col-md-6">
        <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago (Days remaining: <%= item.days_left %> )
        </div>
      <%= link_to "", list_item_path(item.list, item),  class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok', method: :delete, remote: true %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
    <hr>
</div>
```

I cannot seem to figure this out, any help would be much appreciated.

UPDATE

I am clicking on this link

```
<% @lists.each do |list| %>
        <li><%=link_to list.name , list_path(current_user, list), class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' %></li>
      <% end %>
```

Now I am getting a similar error, only now in my Items controller

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find List with 'id'=3 [WHERE "lists"."user_id" = ?]):
  app/controllers/items_controller.rb:48:in `find_list'
```

items controller

```
class ItemsController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :find_list



  def new
    @item = @list.items.new
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    @new_item = Item.new
    @item = @list.items.new(item_params)

    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = "Item added successfully"
    else
      flash[:error] = "There was an error adding your item to the list, please try again."
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  def destroy

    @item = @list.items.find(params[:id])

    if @item.destroy
      flash[:notice]= "#{@item.name} has been completed. Good Job!"
    else
      flash[:error]= "Sorry looks like there was a problem marking your item as complete, please try again."
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
  end

  private

  def find_list
    @list = current_user.lists.find(params[:list_id])
  end

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name)
  end
end
```

Comment: What link are you clicking when you get this error (maybe in your index)? The error is because your path is `/lists/item`. Since the show route expects `lists/:id`, it is assuming the `id` is `item`.

Comment: I am clicking on the link for the individual lists. '<% @lists.each do |list| %>
        <li><%=link_to list.name , list_path(current_user, list), class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' %></li>
      <% end %>'

Comment: `<%=link_to list.name, list, class: 'btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block' %>` should do the trick

Comment: Thanks! @AbM I have made that change but now I am getting a similar error with my items controller. Fairly new to rails and trying to figure out why I keep having these routing issues.

Comment: Where is `@lists` defined? Are you sure the list with `id=3` belongs to the current_user?

Comment: @lists is defined in my users_controller `@user = User.find(params[:id])
    @lists = @user.lists`

Comment: Why are you sending `current_user` as a parameter to `list_path`? List path looks like a path helper that should only take a list.